# Do I really need to put anything in "dependencies"?

Tags: npm, dependencies, npm-install, dependency-management, npm-publish

I'm developing a browser-side package, with several runtime dependencies and developing tools. As suggested, I install them using NPM as `dependencies` and `devDependencies` respectively.

Eventually, before I publish it, I always compile every source file and external dependencies into one minimized file.

When I try to install it in another project, however, I noticed that all "dependencies" packages are also installed. I assume it's a standard NPM behavior, yet these packages should not be needed, as I've already compressed them all into my own .min.js file.

Should I just move them all to "devDependencies"?